# Login Failed PhpPgAdmin in nginx centos

Tags: nginx, centos

I am facing strange problem in centos for phpPgAdmin login, I did all things that are required

in ** /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/conf/config.inc.php  **

```
 $conf['extra_login_security'] = false;
```

I tried with two combination of configurations
in **/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf**

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:


host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                trust
host    all             all             myserver_ip/32       trust
```

=========================2nd=====================================

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:


host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                md5
host    all             all             myserver_ip/32       md5
```

but the Login failed is still coming

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Configure the firewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=5432/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

## 2. configure SELinux as below:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

## 3.configure PostgreSQL

**sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf**

```
IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

## 4. Setup PostgreSQL listening addresses:

**sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

## Then configure phpPgAdmin

**sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpPgAdmin.conf**

```
Require all granted
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of those two pg_hba.conf setups should work ok, although the first is more likely to work (whilst being completely unsecured). The one thing you seem to have left out from the problem description is if you modify the server config lines in /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/conf/config.inc.php. Those must be updated to point to your database server (and will be different depending on if it is a local or remote database).

If that doesn't do it, I'd suggest going to either the PostgreSQL slack team, or #postgresql on Freenode, for live troubleshooting help.